# What is the performance hit for loading a JS file twice, but only parsing it once?

Tags: javascript, performance, browser, include

I'm working with legacy code that frequently loads the same external javascript files many times.

I am trying to decide whether I need to find all the places that **load** `.js` files and prevent them from re-loading the file if it already exists, or if I can get away with simply modifying all `.js` files to prevent them from being **parsed** if they've already been parsed.

For example. Say I have a `.js` file called `utils.js`.

```
if(!utils_Loaded){
   var utils_Loaded = true;
   var utils = function() {

     //javasript code here

   };
} else {
   console.log("utils.js was already loaded, so we skipped parsing it again.");
}
```

However, there are about 500 other includes that are still loading `utils.js`, so in effect, the HTML looks like this:

```
<script src="/utils.js"></script> ...
<script src="/utils.js"></script> ...
<script src="/utils.js"></script> ...
<script src="/utils.js"></script> ...
<script src="/utils.js"></script> ...
<script src="/utils.js"></script> (... etc)
```

So my question is, how will modern browsers handle the multiple loading? I assume the browser will cache the file, but it will still have to pull it into memory again, which is probably small, until multiplied many many times because this is happening **everywhere** in the code, hundreds of files all being loaded multiple times.

Would it be better to check at the point of include?

```
<script>if(!utils_Loaded){$.getScript("utils.js");}</script> ...
<script>if(!utils_Loaded){$.getScript("utils.js");}</script> ...
<script>if(!utils_Loaded){$.getScript("utils.js");}</script> ...
<script>if(!utils_Loaded){$.getScript("utils.js");}</script> ...
<script>if(!utils_Loaded){$.getScript("utils.js");}</script> ...
<script>if(!utils_Loaded){$.getScript("utils.js");}</script> (...etc)
```

Comment: Pretty low. Those requests should all come from the cache.

Comment: `$.getScript` is very different, it loads the script without caching and asynchronously!

Comment: The browsers will pull the file from cache, but, they MUST re-execute the file unless they're smart enough to realize that the execution of the file will have no side effects on the program. Considering the file will at least declare a function/variable, it will have side effects and must be executed.

Comment: Would [require.js](http://requirejs.org) be of any help here?

Answer (score 1):

Might take some time but the best thing to do would clean that up. You can load utils.js once with the page (if its being used as much as you say then it seems silly not to). You can also abstract the loading into a function to help centralize your utils_loaded check.

Answer (score 0):

As long as your web server take use of the Not-modified response, there's a bunch needless GET requests...

btw If you're using ASP/PHP or equal, I suggest making the line into a file and replace with  include_once('tagline.js');

Edit: interesting side-note, did some testing, and seems there's a bug in chrome(23) and Internet Explorer(9) and Opera(12.11) that makes it load just once; even with HTTP header "Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate" :p (but not firefox)